# How to update/edit SQL code to make workable

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very new to SQL and i need to update a piece of SQL code that i need to use for my work but i have no idea on how to make it into a workable piece of code. I have tried editing the code within Oracle SQL Developer but any edits i do it doesn't like at all.

Please can someone help me get the below code workable. The code is supposed to obtain any users that have the same name within the database so i can see any duplicates and then order them in alphabetical order. The code was written a long time ago and i am having trouble trying to edit it so i can use within Oracle SQL Developer.

```
SELECT surname, forename, login_id, site, position "
        + "FROM users "
        + "WHERE (surname, forename) IN "
        +    "( SELECT surname, forename "
        +      "FROM users "
        +      "GROUP BY surname, forename "
        +      "HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ) "
        + "ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC ";
```

I tried the following but to no avail..

```
SELECT surname,
  forename,
login_id,
site_id,
position
FROM users
WHERE surname
forename
FROM users
GROUP BY surname,
forename
HAVING COUNT (*)>1
ORDER BY 1 ASC,
2 ASC;
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (without any quotes or `+`:

```
SELECT surname, forename, login_id, site, position 
FROM users 
WHERE (surname, forename) IN 
        ( SELECT surname, forename 
        FROM users 
        GROUP BY surname, forename 
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ) 
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT surname, forename, login_id, site, position 
FROM users 
WHERE (surname||forename) IN 
        ( SELECT surname||forename 
        FROM users 
        GROUP BY surname, forename 
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ) 
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Comment: the concatenation of `surname` and `forename` is not necessary and may in fact return wrong information.